# How to use Automator

Tags: macos, automator

I'm trying to do an application with the automator in MAC OSX.

This is the command line :

/Users/andreacramarossa/Library/“Application Support”/Steam/SteamApps/common/“Assassins Creed Brotherhood”/“Assassin's Creed Brotherhood.app”/Contents/MacOS/acbmp_sf

I'm doing a shell script

This is the problem the application is giving to me. Anyone can help?

-: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching '"